# Send order data as json code to different URL in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

We need to submit order data like order number, product and shipping data to another url using json in Magento after the user placed an order?

Please don't vote minus if it is not clear I can clarify just If you can help If no please let my question I need a help in this point.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

- try send to ajax or api with your data.
- if you capture after place order, try use event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_success`
  capture and redirect to your url.